# Can I use paired sample t-test for the following problem?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

Suppose there is an experiment that in each trial returns a two vector of probabilities of size $n$. In each trial I select uniformly a number from ${1,\cdots, n}$ and compare that element in this two vectors. I want to see if in a large number of trials, that randomly selected element of first vector is greater than the second one. For this I am planning to compare their mean values according to paired sample $t$-test. I know that the vector elements have specified variance and expected value. With this information is it justified to use this hypothesis test?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there an expectation that the two values will be positively correlated?

Comment: Exactly the opposite is the expectation.

Comment: See also this question http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/47453/16974 on the impact of using a paired t-test for unpaired data (which is your situation), and the impact of using an unpaired t-test for paired data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no expectation of a correlation between the values in the 'pairs' then using a paired t-test will reduce the power of the t-test by reducing the degrees of freedom without a compensating reduction in the variance of the measure.

(If the values are probabilities then they cannot be normally distributed and a standard t-test may be inappropriate. However, if the sample size is large enough the t-test is quite robust to departures from normality, particularly if the actual distribution is symmetrical and the two distributions have similar widths.)