# Is there a difference between a paired two sample t-test and one sample t-test of the pair differences?

Tags: t-test, normality-assumption, paired-data

Suppose two samples X and Z are **dependent** and of equal length. I see two approaches to investigate the possible difference in means:

1) Use a paired t-test if the normality assumption is met for each sample.

2) Subtract the samples from each other and apply a one-sample t-test to test whether the *difference* (X-Z) differs from 0.

Is there a difference in the way the test statistics are calculated? This thread  ([Paired difference t-test vs independent two sample t-test to assess means difference](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139872/paired-difference-t-test-vs-independent-two-sample-t-test-to-assess-means-differ][1])) with an excellent answer suggests **there is not**.

I confess, I often give in to using the test that suits me best for reporting. When both samples approximate normality I use a paired t-test, when they do not but the difference (X-Y) does I use a one-sample t-test. Is the latter approach **wrong**? In the proposed should situation should I always favour option (1) over option (2)?

Comment: What are the test statistics in each case?

Comment: They are exactly the same t(2677) = -23.741. However, if I'd have to criticize someone who is checking whether a sample mean differs from 0 and he (or she) would do a one-sample t-test after checking normality I'd have nothing to comment. But, if that same person would be performing a paired t-test on two samples that _are_ _not_ normally distributed, I'd criticize that person for performing a t-test when normality is violated. So where's the catch? The fact that the one sample t-test was not performed on a _sample_ by strict definition? Just trying to criticize my own approach here!

Comment: I didn't mean what is the value of the test statistic ... I meant the formula you substitute into to get those values. (It's a question with a point. I was hoping once you look at the formulas that you might understand something important about the question)

Comment: Specifically, they are *exactly* the same test with exactly the same assumptions, which relate to normality of the population of differences. The actual assumption is likely never satisfied in practice . The question you need to consider is not "can I detect non-normality?" but "is the non-normality I have going to affect the properties of my test (significance level and power) more than I am prepared to tolerate?" ... which is more of an effect-size kind of question than a hypothesis testing one

Comment: Yup! I did actually look at the formulas, that' why I posted the thread. I was just confused with the subject of the normality assumption regarding the paired t-test. And I completely agree on the latter statements about the normality assumption.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question (community wiki, feel free to adjust), after giving it some more thought and researching a bit:

> Q: Is there a difference in the way the test statistics are calculated?

A: No. I suppose @Glen_b was hinting in that direction. T-statistic remains the same, as do the DF.

> Q: Is the latter approach wrong?

A: No, the former is wrong. As can be read here (http://www.biostathandbook.com/pairedttest.html): **The paired t–test assumes that the differences between pairs are normally distributed**. Performing a t-test without checking the normality of the difference is wrong, regardless of the normality of X or Z (the constituents of the difference).

> Q: In the proposed should situation should I always favour option (1) over option (2)?

A: Either options work *but* normality of the *difference* needs to be verified in either case. You might as well do the one-sample t-test because you need to calculate the difference anyhow.

Comment: +1 though I'm not sure the normality of the difference actually does "need to be verified"; for example (i) I may have a good reason to make an a priori assumption of normality, or (ii) I may actually be quite sure the distribution *isn't* actually normal, but nevertheless be quite sure that the impact on my inference is small.

Comment: I agree, that sounds like a correct adjustment of the answer.