# Using non-parametric bootstrap to assess relative difference between means of two samples

Tags: bayesian, bootstrap

Let's say we have 2 samples, A and B. I'd like to find out which distribution has a higher mean by using non-parametric bootstrap.

My procedure goes like this:

1. Calculate the mean of a resample 1 from sample A: $\bar{x}*$
2. Calculate the mean of a resample 1 from sample B: $\bar{y}*$
3. Calculate relative difference between $(\bar{x*}-\bar{y}*) / \bar{x*}$.
4. Repeat steps 1-3 1000 times to get a distribution of relative differences.

Can interpret the results like that: If the 95% CI doesn't include 0, then the relative difference is significant (alpha=0.05)?

To me, the procedure looks like we are interpreting [non-parametric bootstrap as Bayesian model](https://www.sumsar.net/blog/2015/04/the-non-parametric-bootstrap-as-a-bayesian-model/) that has nothing to do with classical frequentist statistical significance since in that case we should bootstrap scenario in which null hypothesis holds (like [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92542/how-to-perform-a-bootstrap-test-to-compare-the-means-of-two-samples) or [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/404472/appropriateness-of-nonparametric-bootstrap-methods-to-assess-difference-between) or permutation test) and then compare it to the actual relative difference.

Comment: I believe that one could do a permutation test for the difference of two means. I don't know why we would bootstrap re-sample in this situation.

Comment: @JTH I agree a permutation test would be a standard approach. However, I'm interested in interpretation of the approach described above.

Comment: Why would that be a bayesian interpretation? Significance levels and confidence intervals are closely related, and one can be obtained from the other for any test. This is as frequentist as it can get.